# How to replace specific rows in a table with rows form another table, other than using 2 loops?

Tags: abap

I have 2 internal tables, A and B, of the same type. A has many records, while B has some of the records in Table A (that is with equal key fields) but with different values on non-key fields.
How can I replace those rows in A with their respective rows at B without using 2 different LOOPs (that is LOOP AT A and for each iteration at A, LOOP AT B to find the respective row and replace it)?
Below is the structure of these tables.

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF tab1,
      bukrs TYPE bukrs,
      belnr TYPE belnr,
      gjahr TYPE gjahr,
      buzei TYPE buzei,

      "above are the key fields
      "below are the non-key fields

      blart TYPE blart,
      bldat TYPE bldat,
      bschl TYPE bschl,
      menge TYPE menge,
      meins TYPE meins,
      dmbtr TYPE dmbtr,
      waers TYPE waers,
      zstatus TYPE c LENGTH 1,
      END OF tab1.
```

Comment: Please edit your question to ask only one question. What did you try? What issue do you have?

Comment: @SandraRossi I removed the 2nd question. I think the post is pretty self explanatory and I can't think of adding any other detail. How can I do the above task without using 2 loops?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the loop through table B by finding the corresponding line with the [READ TABLE](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_755_index_htm/7.55/en-us/abapread_table_free.htm) command.

```
LOOP AT gt_tab1 ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<line1>).
    READ TABLE gt_tab2 ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<line2>) WITH KEY
        bukrs = <line1>-bukrs
        belnr = <line1>-belnr
        gjahr = <line1>-gjahr
        buzei = <line1>-buzei.
    IF sy-subrc = 0.
        MOVE-CORRESPONDING <line2> TO <line1>.
    ENDIF.
ENDLOOP.
```

Now what READ TABLE usually does is perform a loop over the table until it found the first matching record. So you didn't actually gain anything except making your code a bit shorter and more readable.

However, there are ways to speed up the performance of READ TABLE. The first is to declare the table you read from with [a primary or a secondary key](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_755_index_htm/7.55/en-us/abensecondary_key_guidl.htm) and then use that key in the READ TABLE. Here is an example with the hashed key variant:

```
 DATA gt_tab2 TYPE TABLE OF tab1 
     WITH UNIQUE HASHED KEY key1 COMPONENTS bukrs belnr gjahr buzei.

 "...

 READ TABLE gt_tab2 ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<line2>) 
    USING KEY key1 COMPONENTS
        bukrs = <line1>-bukrs
        belnr = <line1>-belnr
        gjahr = <line1>-gjahr
        buzei = <line1>-buzei.
```

The result is that you speed up the linear search time to logarithmic time (with a NON-UNIQUE SORTED KEY) or to constant time (with a UNIQUE HASHED KEY).

This of course requires that you have control over the declaration of the second table. This is not always the case, for example when you implement an interface or event function module. But in that case there is still one thing you can do:

1. SORT the table by the fields you are going to search it with later (or a copy of the table, if you are in a context where you can't change the order)
2. Use READ TABLE with the BINARY SEARCH addition

Using binary search reduces the runtime of READ TABLE from linear to logarithmical. But note that when the table is not correctly sorted, it will fail to find rows even though they exist.

```
SORT gt_tab2 BY bukrs belnr gjahr buzei.

LOOP AT gt_tab1 ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<line1>).
    READ TABLE gt_tab2 ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<line2>) 
      WITH KEY
        bukrs = <line1>-bukrs
        belnr = <line1>-belnr
        gjahr = <line1>-gjahr
        buzei = <line1>-buzei
      BINARY SEARCH.
    IF sy-subrc = 0.
        MOVE-CORRESPONDING <line2> TO <line1>.
    ENDIF.
ENDLOOP.
```